# Blocking adsense ad units for a particular country

Tags: adsense

So I have got one hater in India who bombarded on my adsense ad units. Luckily I didn't get banned from Google. I have blocked Indian visitors from my site using iq-blockcountry plugin (wordpress). Now I want to know if there's any procedure so that I can allow the Indian visitors but hide the adsense units from them? I don't want to block all visitors just because of one foolish person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search gave me this. 
This plugin seems to have this feature:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ad-injection/faq/

```
How can I show different ads to people in different countries?

If you install the Country Filter plugin (with the IP database) then you can use the following code in the direct ad insertion modes. This will not work in mfunc mode!

<?php if (function_exists('isCountryInFilter')) { ?>
<?php if(isCountryInFilter(array("uk"))) { ?>

UK advert

<?php } else { ?>

Global advert

<?php } } ?>
```

-- since above is a paying option. what you can do is .

use remote_addr to get your visitors ip

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

next use a networkservice that can provide you this information, or you can make functions for that yourself using available databases.

--- your easiest solution would be to use `geolocation`, but then your users have to agree with this.

Comment: Country Filter WordPress plugin is not available for free :/

Comment: So it seems, you could program this quite easily. If you get the users country just a simple if else would do. No idea what your dev skills are?

Comment: From where can I get the IP addresses of a country? (for free obviously)

Comment: It's not our job to google for you. Or look around here.
I'll guide you . Look for
remote_addr > this is how you can get your visitors ip. 
then look for services on how to retrieve the country from that. I'll add some to my answer above.